AWS AppSync does not validate input field types and is not throwing any error
I have AWS AppSync API with lambda resolvers (Typescript) which works quite well. However I found out that apparently there is no validation on the input field type happening when the API is called from a client (Postman) and I was wondering why?
Example:
Given the following query defined in my schema.graphql:
extend type Query {
  getUsers(
    page: PageRequest
    query: String
    userIds: [String]!
  ): PaginatedUsers!

The userIds is non-nullable and when I go to the aws console and execute the query with userIds = null I get the expected error:
"Validation error of type WrongType: argument 'userIds' with value 'NullValue{}' must not be null @ 'getUsers'"

However when I go to Postman I can do this:
query MyQuery ($query: PageRequest, $userIds: [String!] = null) {
  getUsers(page: $query, userIds: $userIds) {
    data {
      id
      name
    }
}

And pass null for userIds and I do not get any error and my resolver lambda is executed with userIds === null.
This is my response mapping vtl:
#if($context.result && $context.result.error)
  $util.error($context.result.error.message, $context.result.error.type, null, $context.result.error.details) ## Handled error response
#elseif($context.error)
  $util.error($context.error.message, $util.defaultIfNullOrEmpty($context.error.type, "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"), $context.result) ## Unhandled error response
#else
  $util.toJson($context.result) ## Success response
#end


and this is my request mapping vtl:
{
  "version" : "2018-05-29",
  "operation": "Invoke",
  "payload": {
    "field": "$context.info.fieldName",
    "arguments":  $utils.toJson($context.arguments),
  }
}

I would expect that in case the input field (userIds) does not match the schema definition (null) Appsync would give me the same error when I would execute the query in the aws console.
What am I missing?
